# how to describe map and list in protobuf?

Tags: types, protocol-buffers

I have a c++ program, wrapping a List type, it looks like python list: **type of element is arbitrary within a list**. So with the Map : **both key and value are arbitrary type**, how can I describe them in protobuf?

Answer (score 1):

Protobuf demand type must be **Specific**. It's not allowed to use **arbitrary type**.